# Spring Boot Unit Test with @Autowired how to get it to to work without starting entire Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, autowired

I am trying to unit test configuration of a class annotated with `@Configuration`.  The class is fairly simple:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "feed")
public class SpringNyseFeedConfig extends FeedConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringNyseFeedConfig.class);  

    public SpringNyseFeedConfig() {
        LOG.debug("ctor():created {}", SpringNyseFeedConfig.class);
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void completeConfig() {
        LOG.debug("completeConfig(): validating configuration...");
        postConfigure().validate();  // need to set final properties and validate
    }
}
```

The unit test is also simple:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SpringNyseFeedConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private SpringNyseFeedConfig config;
    
    @Test
    void propertiesReadAsExpected() {
        assertNotNull(config);
        ServerConnection requestServer = config.getRequestServer();
        assertEquals("192.168.1.200", requestServer.getHost());
        ...
        ...         
    }

}
```

The test is getting the `config` injected correctly, and configured with properties read from an `application-test.yml` file.

The problem is that the test causes Spring initializes all the Beans in the application (which is time consuming).

I've tried about a half dozen suggestions to try to limit the test to only instantiating the SpringNyseFeedConfig object only, but they have all resulted in either not injecting anything at all (config == null), or injecting an object not configured from the `yml` file (i.e. no properties set).

How can I update the unit test so that it will read the file and auto-configure and inject the SpringNyseFeedConfig object without instantiating every other component in the application?

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated annotation `@TestPropertySource` to enable testing of `ConfigurationProperties`. This should work as expected:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = SpringNyseFeedConfig .class)
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
public class SpringNyseFeedConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private SpringNyseFeedConfig config;
// ...
}
```

Please note: I'm intentionally using properties instead YAML file because the latter doesn't work properly with tests.

Based on: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing-configurationproperties

Answer (score 1):

Use `ApplicationRunner` to assemble the context.

```kotlin
// kotlin code fragment
class YourTests{

    private val contextRunner = ApplicationContextRunner()

    @Test
    fun testAppProperties() {
        contextRunner
            .withUserConfiguration(YourConfig::class.java)
            .run {
                val bean: YourBean = it.getBean(YourBean::class.java)
                assertThat(bean.baseUrl).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8080")

            }
    }
}
```

Java version:

```java
public class YourTests{

    private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner();

    @Test
    public void testAppProperties() {
        contextRunner
            .withUserConfiguration(YourConfig.class)
            .run( ctx -> {
                var bean = ctx.getBean(YourBean.class);
                assertThat(bean.baseUrl).isEqualTo("http://localhost:8080");

           });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Kotlin. The question is about Java.

Comment: @Mar-Z It is easy to convert it to Java.